# Magento2 cron of custom group does not get scheduled automatically

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron, core-config-data

I have a default ddev magento2.4.6 environment running locally on my mac.

My custom module should be scheduled and executed as cron, which works fine as long as I run it from terminal via `php n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run module`

But it wont be executed automatically via cron and I dont understand why.

I have created an `etc/crontab.xml`inside my module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="customgroup">
        <job instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\UpdateUrlKeys" method="execute" name="job_name">
            <schedule>45 9 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

and a cron_group.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="customgroup">
        <schedule_generate_every>15</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>30</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>60</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
        <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
    </group>
</config>
```

I find my job correctly in db table `core_config_data` and I can also configure the values of my `cron_groups.xml` in magento2 backend under `store -> config -> advanced -> system`

Is there something I am missing?

Appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: Verify that the cron job is being executed by checking the cron_schedule table in your Magento database.

Comment: HI @Harun, thats the problem - my cron is never listed there automatically. Like I mentiod before, as soon as I run it manually it gets listed in cron_schedule and the status changes from ``running`` to ``success``afters its done

Comment: Look for the entry in core_config_data with the path crontab/jobs/customgroup/job_name/schedule/cron_expr. Verify that the cron_expr value matches your desired schedule.

Comment: Hi @Harun, unfortunately I dont have this entry

Comment: If my cron expression is set to ``* * * * *``it works, but otherwise it does not...